# How to remove brackets around substrings of a specific length?

Tags: python, regex

I'm able to remove brackets entirely from a string using the following Python function:

```
def bracket_remove(smi):
    remove_chars = ['[', ']']
    return ''.join((filter(lambda i: i not in remove_chars, smi)))
```

However, there are some cases where I want to keep bracketed sections.  Specifically, I only want to remove brackets if the brackets enclose a single character.  For example, `[N][C@H]([C])[C](=O)[O]` would become `N[C@H](C)C(=O)O`.  Regular expressions seem like the way to go here, but I haven't been able to find much that's relevant for this problem.  The closest regular expression solution I could find was:

```
import re
test_str = "[N][C@H]([C])[C](=O)[O]"
m = re.search(r"\[(\w+)\]", test_str)
print(m.group(1))
```

This returns only the first instance of bracketed characters (N), while I had thought it would identify cases where multiple characters were present between brackets.  How would I modify this expression to find only the substrings with multiple characters (alphanumeric or otherwise) between brackets?

Comment: `re.findall()` returns all the matches.

Comment: But what does that have to do with replacing, which is done with `re.sub()`?

Comment: `\w+` won't match `C@H`. `\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscore, not `@`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for regular expression composition (I have no association with the site).  You can put in your regex and test data and fiddle with it until it does what you like.

Comment: @DanielFarrell thanks for the resource, regex has always been a stumbling block for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\[(\w)]', r'\1', text)
# Or any char other than brackets
re.sub(r'\[([^][])]', r'\1', text)
```

See [regex # demo](https://regex101.com/r/1GoFhb/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/1GoFhb/2).

*Details*

- `\[`  - matches a `[` char
- `(\w)` - captures any letter/digit/connector punctuation into Group 1
- `([^][])` - captures any char other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - matche a `]` char.

The `\1` in the replacement pattern replaces each match with the contents of Group  1 value.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZX3a7x):

```py
import re
text = '[N][C@H]([C])[C](=O)[O]'
print(re.sub(r'\[(\w)]', r'\1', text))
# => N[C@H](C)C(=O)O
# Or any char other than brackets
print(re.sub(r'\[([^][])]', r'\1', text))
# => N[C@H](C)C(=O)O
```

Comment: Tried this suggestion and it worked perfectly with other examples.  Thanks for the explanation.